# How to style tooltip size under ui-select-choices

Tags: css, angularjs

I am building small website for homework and I have got stuck with
styling `tooltip` size. The `tooltip` is a attribute in `span` tag under
`ui-select-choices`. I want to edit the style of the `tooltip` only in this dropdown

```
<ui-select
        autofocus
        class="temp-class">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select from here" tooltip="{{$select.selected.id}}" tooltip-placement="bottom-left" tooltip-append-to-body="true">
        {{"Select from here"}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in items">
        <span ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search" tooltip="{{item.name}}" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-append-to-body="true"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
    <ui-select-no-choice>
        None
    </ui-select-no-choice>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: span[tooltip="itemname"] - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/fkwp07x2/1/

Comment: but the item name is dynamic @LuísP.A.

Comment: So, add a class or another attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS to target the tooltip attribute in `span`

```
span[tooltip]{
  color: red;
}
```

It takes effect for all tooltips regardless of tooltip name.

```css
span[tooltip] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ui-select autofocus class="temp-class">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select from here" tooltip="{{$select.selected.id}}" tooltip-placement="bottom-left" tooltip-append-to-body="true">
    {{"Select from here"}}
  </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="item in items">
    <span ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search" tooltip="teste" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-append-to-body="true">sdfsdf</span>
  </ui-select-choices>
  <ui-select-no-choice>
    None
  </ui-select-no-choice>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. the tooltip content is dynamic value and not "teste". i tried to add class attribute to span and also doesn't work

Comment: I haven't mentioned "teste" or any other value in CSS. Please share some minimal working code and I'll debug it.